# Unique user having unique values in two php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I'll move to the query straight away. I have an html form having two fields(Email and a numeric id) asking from every user. Both of the values in every row can be different or exactly the same. The form is dynamic and as per the requirement asks for multiple emails and numeric ids. Both values are processed as php arrays(email array and number array). My request for all of you to help me out with the query is that to find out the UNIQUE ROW which is having the unique email and the associated numeric value should be unique in the whole array as well.

Please help me out, it is such an important thing for me.
Thanx in advance. form example below:

```
 1. email-1 num-1
 2. email-2 num-2
 3. email-3 num-3
 4. email-4 num-4
 5. email-2 num-1
 6. email-4 num-1
 7. email-5 num-5
 8. email-2 num-1
```

NOW, WE HAVE TO LOOK FOR THE UNIQUE ROW OR ROWS... THESE INPUTS CAN BE IN HUNDREDS.

This is how I am displaying my array values to the next page -

```
<?php foreach($BX_EMAIL as $a=>$b){ ?>
<?php echo $a+1; ?>
<?php echo $BX_EMAIL[$a]; ?>
<?php echo $BX_NUM[$a]; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, the expected output page after this page is just to display the unique rows(unique email with the associated unique number).

Sample input -

```
 1. abc@pqr.com 10000
 2. pqr@abc.com 11223
 3. rst@hpq.com 10000
 4. tps@lkc.com 90909
 5. pqr@abc.com 90909
 6. wps@gps.com 11223
 7. tts@pps.com 88997
 8. abc@pqr.com 11223
 9. wps@gps.com 10000
 10.tts@lpg.com 78789
```

Now, the output of the above input should be -
As per the manual check as there are only 10 rows, the result is as follows -

```
abc@pqr.com
10000  

abc@pqr.com
11223  

wps@gps.com
10000  

rst@hpq.com
10000  

wps@gps.com
11223  

pqr@abc.com
11223  

pqr@abc.com
90909  

tps@lkc.com
90909  

*********************  

tts@lpg.com
78789  

*********************  

tts@pps.com
88997
```

Now in the above output there are THREE groups - 1st group is same as there are same NUM and EMAIL in each other which makes the records same. However the 2nd and 3rd group is not connected anywhere with any record. This is the expected separated output required by me.

I hope this time i was clear enough. Now please think a bit more as per the situation.

Comment: Great story, what have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you store the values in the arrays? Please provide sample input and expected output

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you for your interest. I am sorry but i am one of the newbies in php, still tried some array functions from php.net, but did not reach any where. I was confused in putting them to loop. So, will appreciate your help from the scratch. What I have right now - the form and the values can be displayed on next page. Don't know the rest...

Comment: Any suggestion/help? Jack, msfoster...

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: Hello msfoster, I m sorry for the delay. But now i have made the required additions to the question as you suggested. Please undo your markdown. My question is genuine.

Comment: I did not down vote your question. By unique, do you mean **occurring only once**?

Comment: YES, Both values should be unique in their respective arrays. That makes the complete row unique as i have shown in the sample output.

Comment: Your choice of words are a bit confusing. Confirm this: **Find the email/num pairs that each only occur once in their respective arrays**

Comment: Exactly, you are right! However both unique values should be from the same row. Because if in one row the NUM is unique but the EMAIL is not, then does not qualify as A COMPLETE UNIQUE ROW for me.

Comment: i have updated my answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided I think this solution is sufficient:

```
// ok - this is a reproduction of the two arrays you've got
$BX_EMAIL = array("1@domain.com", "2@domain.com", "3@domain.com", "2@domain.com");
$BX_NUM = array(1,2,3,2);

// merge the two arrays into two-dimensional array
$BX = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($BX_EMAIL); $i++) 
    $BX[] = array($BX_EMAIL[$i], $BX_NUM[$i]);

// generate one-dimensional array of byte stream values
$bs = array_map("serialize", $BX);

//get unique values
$bs_unique = array_unique($bs);

// revert back to two-dimensional array
$result = array_map("unserialize", $bs_unique);

var_dump($result);
```

**UPDATE**  Modified according to edited question

```
// ok - this is a reproduction of the two arrays you've got
$BX_EMAIL = array(
    "abc@pqr.com", "pqr@abc.com", "rst@hpq.com", "tps@lkc.com", 
    "pqr@abc.com","wps@gps.com", "tts@pps.com",
    "abc@pqr.com", "wps@gps.com","tts@lpg.com");
$BX_NUM = array(10000,11223,10000,90909,90909,11223,88997,11223,10000,78789);

// create two-dimensional array
$BX = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($BX_EMAIL); $i++) 
    $BX[] = array($BX_EMAIL[$i], $BX_NUM[$i]);

// find occurrences for each array
$occurrences_email = array_count_values($BX_EMAIL);
$occurrences_num = array_count_values($BX_NUM);

//filter BX on email and number only occurring once
$result = array_filter($BX, function($value) use(&$occurrences_email, &$occurrences_num) {
    return $occurrences_email[$value[0]] == 1 && $occurrences_num[$value[1]] == 1;
});

var_dump($result);
```

The keys of `$BX` are still kept, so you might want to reset the keys:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Hi msfoster, first of all thank you so much for trying and spending your time for the sake of help. I am sorry but the solution which you have provided is working halfway and only for EMAIL values. Suppose we have all same values for NUM, then it doesn't show the unique row as there is no unique row at that time.

Comment: Do you want unique emails and unique numbers separated? I thought the combination of the two made the actual value.

Comment: Yes, the combination of two will make the actual value but both inputs of a particular row should be different from every other row individually to make that row unique.

Comment: Ah! Is it working on your machine? I feel sorry, but it doesn't display anything on screen. Looks like some syntax error or something else.

Comment: Yes it is working. Which PHP version are you running? Enable error reporting.

Comment: Wow! Its working very fine now. Thank you so much msfoster. You have spent so much of your precious time on my resolution. You are a very PHP programmer. Tell me if you teach PHP online. I want to join your classes. :D GOD Bless You.